# Tensor Flow Error, "Failed to load native TensorFlow runtime", and I don't know what to do about it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, artificial-intelligence

Here is the error message (yes very long), and I'm not sure how to solve it, i installed tensor flow with the pip command, and I know there is no error in the code since i copied a file from github, and wanted to test it out (link to it here: https://github.com/llSourcell/pong_neural_network_live). If anyone has a solution I would much appreciate it thanks!

**

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Aritra/Downloads/pong_neural_network_live-master/RL.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 6): Symbol not found: _SecKeyCopyExternalRepresentation
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/../libtensorflow_framework.2.dylib
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors*
```

**

Comment: You are on MacOS. What OS version do you run? What exactly did you execute for installing, `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: The error message provides a link which they recommend you consult, have you done that? Also, searching online for that error returns plenty of results, have you gone through all those?

Comment: I'm on version 10.9.5 on mac, is that the reason why? If so, is there a way around it?

Comment: 10.9.5 is pretty old - try older versions of `tensorflow`, e.g. `pip install tensorflow==1.7` or even `pip install tensorflow==1.5`.

Comment: thanks, i tried typing this into the terminal, and also tried using pip3 instead of pip but this error came up every time:                                                                       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.5 (from versions: 2.0.1)...... not sure what to do about this, but i guess I can't do RL then :(